# What is the Google Bigquery-like equivalent in AWS for analytics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena

A previous workflow of mine had our analytics setup like so: basically all data stored in a mysql instance which was then piped in to our instance of Google Bigquery for our more demanding analytics uses. I've recently changed places to an Amazon shop where we collect most of our data in Athena and Aurora, but we don't really have a good analytics dump to do more intensive and demanding queries on the data.

I really liked the web UI for GBQ and the ability for cross-database joins (makes it easy to leverage sandbox queries for ad-hoc work) but I don't know what an equivalent workhorse for AWS would be. **Is there some AWS solution that has a standardized web UI, supports flexible sandbox collaboration, and also has the GBQ-like firepower behind the processing for about the same price point?** I've heard that Redshift isn't nearly to the same scale for processing power like GBQ is (unless you set it up to be billed out the nose, if that's even true), but that it does have a browser-based query editor as of recent updates.

I'm assessing options that could be better than our current leveraging of Redash, which coming from the GCP ecosystem, makes me feel sad with how woefully limited it feels by comparison.

Any thoughts, suggestions, demos I should try?

Comment: There is none. Sorry to say this. BigQuery is the hidden gem of the cloud, available only on GCP.

Comment: You can try checking [Using the Query Editor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/query-editor.html#using-query-editor), according with the AWS documentation thi is still in beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is none. Sorry to say this. BigQuery is the hidden gem of the cloud, available only on GCP.

If you consider moving to BQ.

You could setup a VPN between AWS-and-GCP, then setup a replica for the relational database to be in Cloud SQL on GCP, than you can use BigQuery to run external queries and can store in BQ. As in this [slide](https://www.slideshare.net/martonkodok/applying-bigquery-ml-on-ecommerce-data-analytics/11).

Comment: Wrong - AWS Athena and AWS Redshift are both analogous to BQ.

Comment: Not quite, Redshift is not even close to what BQ can do. Redshift, as per their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html) is a more scalable `Postgres` replacement whereas BQ is something completely different.